# How to add additional behaviour to default on-click behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a button A. 
Onclick, there is a js library that I am using that does behavior B.
I want to do behaviour C and then execute behaviour B. Is there anyway for me to inject behaviour C before behaviour B?

When I try to override the onclick event, what happens is only behaviour C executes. B does not.

More specifically, I am using the iris color picker as the js library that on click of a html class="color-picker", a dropdown color picker opens(ie something like this...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjDJI.jpg)

I want to add some functionality to the iris onclick handler for $('.color-picker'). For example, I want to make it so that once I click on the color-picker input textbox, I find the uncle of the current color picker div wise.

```
<div class ="dad"> Dad</div>
    <div class = "son color-picker"> son </div>
<div class = "auntie"> Aunt </div>
<div class = "uncle"> Uncle </div>
```

My attempts so far:

```
$('.color-picker').click(function (event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var parent = $(target).parent()[0];
    var uncle = $(parent).siblings()[1];
    ///other code follows....
});
```

But the thing is that I override the default functionality B, and only do Behavior C(ie find the uncle of the clicked color-picker). How do I do both behaviour B and C without specifically copy pasting code from the iris library or modifying the library?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `addEventListener` before you import your library to fire your callback first.

```
<div id="clickable"></div>
<script>
    $("clickable").click(function(){
        // your code
    });
</script>
<script src="external library"></script>
```

If you need to import your external library in head, make sure it's executed on `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()` event and put your click handler after the element (it's usually placed before `</body>`) you wanna target with it (!without the `DOMReady` event as it would otherwise fire after your external library code).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something really simple, if the click function has already been defined, capturing the current definition in a manner like the following and then executing the previous function if it exists.

```
var _cp_click = $('.color-picker')[0].click;

$('.color-picker').click(function (event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var parent = $(target).parent()[0];
    var uncle = $(parent).siblings()[1];
    if (_cp_click != null) {_cp_click();}
    ///other code follows....
});
```

This will preserve the previously defined click function and then allow you to define your own and later call the previously defined version.